# Existence and Uniqueness of Minimization problem in Sobolev space

Tags: partial-differential-equations

"Consider the functional
$$ F(u) = \int_{\Omega}[ \frac{1}{2} \nabla u(x) |^2 + g(x) u(x)] dx $$
and the set 
$$K = \{  v \in H^1 (\Omega): v = 0\   \text{on} \  \partial \Omega\  in\  the \ sense\  of\  traces \}$$

where $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ is bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary $\partial \Omega$, $ g \in L^2(\Omega)$, symbol $\nabla u $ means the gradient vector of function $u$.

Let $ u \in H^1(\Omega)$ be the solution of the problem " Minimize f(v) among all functions v belonging to set K". Assuming that such a solution exits, derive the partial differential equation that is solved by u. In what sense does u solve this partial differential equation? And show that the solution of minimization problem exists and is unique (with some assumptions on the function $g$)"

I thinks It is one kind of elliptical problem, but the space $H^1(\Omega)$ instead of $C^1 (\Omega)$ . However i think it still the same. Right?

But I can not solve the existence and uniqueness.

Thanks you very much

Comment: You need some theorem which allows you to conclude that a sequence of minimizers converges in an appropriate sense, and you need to know that your function is lower semicontinuous with respect to the kind of convergence you can prove -- do you have this kind of theorem in your notes? (This is an exercise, isn't it?)

Comment: No, I dont have such theorem that you said. Can you upload the link, or file about it?

Comment: Have a look at this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_method_in_the_calculus_of_variations and maybe follow the references. If you have access to a library you may want to look at Dacorognas book mentioned there.

Comment: I cant not find that in what senses a sequence of minimizers converges ?

Comment: The general reasoning is usually that a sequence of minimizers is norm bounded (the structure of your functional must imply this) and the at norm bounded sequences on Hilbert spaces contain a weakly convergent subsequence.

Comment: So the PDE will be  $- \nabla u = g$ and $ u = 0 $ on $\partial \Omega$ , right?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the differential equation:

You have to differentiate the equation in direction of a testfunction $\phi\in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ (or taken from some other suitable test function space):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dt }F(u+t\phi)|_{t=0} &=& \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\int_\Omega\frac{1}{2}\langle \nabla (u+t\phi),\nabla (u+t\phi)\rangle + g(u+t\phi)\, dx 
\\
&=&\int_\Omega \langle \nabla u,\nabla \phi\rangle + g\phi \,dx 
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Now you have to get rid of the term involving derivatives of $\phi$. If all functions were smooth, you could integrate by parts (apply the divergence theorem to $\int \text{div}(\phi\nabla u)\, dx)$:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&=& \int_\Omega \phi(- \Delta u +g)\, dx + \int_{\partial \Omega} \phi\langle\nabla u, n\rangle \,dS = \int_\Omega\phi (- \Delta u +g) \, dx 
\end{eqnarray}
$$
since $\phi$ vanishes at the boundary. So the resulting PDE is $$\Delta u = g$$ in the distributional sense.